# Pandas json_Normalize Outputs only 1 Huge Row

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to turn JSON data into a Pandas dataframe in Python.

Whenever I use `df = pd.json_normalize(data)`

The output is 1 rows x 285750 columns.
[Screenshot of output in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVFiH.png)

I am ultimately trying to get a dataframe that has a row for each item 'name'

This is a sample of the JSON:

```
    {
        "success": true,
        "currency": "USD",
        "timestamp": 1644687375,
        "items_list": {
            "&#39Blueberries&#39 Buckshot | NSWC SEAL": {
                "name": "&#39Blueberries&#39 Buckshot | NSWC SEAL",
                "price": {
                    "7_days": {
                        "average": 1.46,
                        "median": 1.45,
                        "sold": "50",
                        "standard_deviation": "5.38",
                        "lowest_price": 1.33,
                        "highest_price": 1.54
                    },
                    "30_days": {
                        "average": 1.43,
                        "median": 1.43,
                        "sold": "3157",
                        "standard_deviation": "5.51",
                        "lowest_price": 1.06,
                        "highest_price": 1.58
                    },
                    "all_time": {
                        "average": 1.2,
                        "median": 1.39,
                        "sold": "123024",
                        "standard_deviation": "14.02",
                        "lowest_price": 0.83,
                        "highest_price": 1.74
                    }
                },
                "first_sale_date": "1607036400"
            },
            "&#39Medium Rare&#39 Crasswater | Guerrilla Warfare": {
                "name": "&#39Medium Rare&#39 Crasswater | Guerrilla Warfare",
                "price": {
                    "7_days": {
                        "average": 4.68,
                        "median": 4.66,
                        "sold": "49",
                        "standard_deviation": "1.68",
                        "lowest_price": 4.55,
                        "highest_price": 4.81
                    },
                    "30_days": {
                        "average": 4.58,
                        "median": 4.58,
                        "sold": "4584",
                        "standard_deviation": "5.15",
                        "lowest_price": 3.71,
                        "highest_price": 5.21
                    },
                    "all_time": {
                        "average": 7.24,
                        "median": 4.76,
                        "sold": "30250",
                        "standard_deviation": "22.02",
                        "lowest_price": 3.71,
                        "highest_price": 15.16
                    }
                },
                "first_sale_date": "1632348000"
            }
    }
}
```

I'm very new to coding in general, so I opted to not include the other solutions I've tried incase they are erroneous or don't make sense. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.json_normalize(data["items_list"].values())`

Comment: @KarlThornton That worked! The dataframe looks exactly how I was hoping. Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data["items_list"]` is a dict where the `.values()` is a "list" of the data you need. This can be passed directly to [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to produce the needed output.

```
>>> pd.json_normalize(data["items_list"].values())
                                                name first_sale_date  ...  price.all_time.lowest_price  price.all_time.highest_price
0           &#39Blueberries&#39 Buckshot | NSWC SEAL      1607036400  ...                         0.83                          1.74
1  &#39Medium Rare&#39 Crasswater | Guerrilla War...      1632348000  ...                         3.71                         15.16

[2 rows x 20 columns]
```